# How can I write a procmail recipe to execute script without affecting the original message

Tags: email, procmail

I want to use procmail to trigger a script to run when a certain email message is encountered but **I do not want to change, alter, or prevent delivery of the original message.**

Will this procmail recipe work?

```
    :0 fw
    * ^From: .*numbchild@gmail\.com
    {
        :0 c
        * ^Subject:\/.*
        | /bin/sh $HOME/bin/notify.sh "Thread ('$MATCH') updated" "Body"
    }
```

Comment: Indidentally, the `fw` flags on the outer recipe are superfluous, if not outright erroneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/procmailrc.5.html#contenttoc2):

```
   c    Generate a carbon copy of this mail.  This  only  makes  sense  on
        delivering  recipes.
```

So yes, the `c` flag will cause the message to also be delivered with the next matching recipe.